# Discord.js converting Javascript with console into embeds for discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm working on a bot right now and when looking at the api I get this as the example of how it'll work.

```
(async () => {
    console.log(await bookwebsite.getHomepage(1))
})()
{
  results: [ { bookId: 'web id',
       thumbnail: 'thumbnail link',
       title: 'book title' },
     { bookId: 'web id',
       thumbnail: 'thumbnail link',
       title: 'book title' },
     { bookId: 'web id',
       thumbnail: 'thumbnail link',
       title: 'book title' },
       ...
  ],
}
```

Can anyone lead me in the right direction on how to translate this from a console log script to running it within discord embeds? [API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nhentai-js) **WARNING NSFW**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not extremely sure what you're meaning as of translating console into embeds but I'm guessing you're trying to format the data returned in the api in to a embed in Discord.

```js
const bookwebsite = require('nhentai-js');

(async () => {
  var data = await bookwebsite.getHomepage(1);
  data = data.results.slice(0, 25);
  if(!data) return message.channel.send('Failed to retrieve data from api. ')
  // slices to avoid discord embeds going beyond 25 fields
  var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Results found');
  // For each the data that's received(after its trimmed)
  data.forEach(d=>{
    // For every object inside of data, it takes the name and sets it as a field title and sets the description of the field as the id and thumbnail link. 
    embed.addField(`Name: ${d.title}`, `ID: ${d.bookId}\nThumbnail: ${d.thumbnail}`)
  })
  // Embeds done, now need to send into the channel
  message.channel.send(embed)
})()
```

If you need any help further on, please comment below.

Comment: There is no `Array#trim()` method. Did you mean `.slice()`?

Comment: I'm getting an error saying data.forEach is not a function.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be working a lot better now! Only issue I'm having now is that the thumbnail link isn't working and only outputting "link"

Comment: Oh, I've tried the source code and I realised that the thumbnail link that is returned only gives a base64 gif/img which would be complicated to decode back into a link, therefore its a text but in hyperlink display, therefore would only show link!

Comment: Okay is it supposed to be hyperlinked because it isn't when embedded

Comment: Edited the source again!

Comment: Now All I'm getting is "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAPhttps:///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"

Comment: Yes, that's what the api returns, I'm afraid I'm unable to help you with that. You can ask another question, I'm sure someone will be able to help!